# Plane in Trevor's Sandy Shore Hangar after Nervous Ron mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I completed Trevor's "Nervous Ron" mission. At the very end of the mission Trevor entered the captured plane into the hangar and it was said that he took possession of the hangar. After some time, I visited the hangar again and there was no plane. I would like to ask whether the plane simply disappears after the mission and it is correct behavior, or I encountered a game bug because there should be that gathered plane in the hangar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the plane is only there for the mission I believe, because the same thing happened to me. They aren't very expensive in the store anyway, but I still wish they gave it to you. Happy flying!

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me, so I'm pretty sure it was just for the mission.
I haven't played the game for a few months, so I could be wrong here, but Trevor has to own a hangar at the main airport (bottom of the map) in order to store planes to use later on.